# Angular doesn't send cookies on CORS

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, cors

I have an `App Engine` server hosting an AngularJS application that makes `CORS` requests to some `Cloud Endpoints` APIs on another `App Engine` server. As per the [$http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) I have enabled it to send credentials in cross-domain requests by settinga default header:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

The front-end server has an associated custom domain with SSL support, and makes requests via `HTTPS` (so that both the ends are basically `HTTPS`).
My goal is sending an authentication cookie to the backend in order to manage resource access authorization, but for some reason this cookie never gets sent.
I do see the cookie in the request when the two servers are running locally (frontend: http://localhost:8081, backend: http://localhost:8080), but not when they're deployed.

What am I missing there?

[angular http Documetation i follwed](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this header to your HTTP calls `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to send an authorization cookie over CORS to a different (sub)domain?

To do this, you need to permit CORS requests on the initial page load, use 'withCredentials' as you have detailed as well as have a cookie for the targeted cross domain call. If it's cross domain, you'll have to write the cookie in js code, if it's a sibling subdomain make sure the cookie domain starts with a dot `.domain.com`, and the cookie will then be shared across all subdomains of the domain.

Localhost can play havoc with this kind of testing because the domain relationships are different (i.e. Not sibling subdomains) - you can try using a local proxy to set up a scenario which maps subdomains to a loop back address.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean with "write the cookie in js code"? I'm currently relying on `Google Identity Toolkit` to manage OAuth2 authentication and get back the authentication token. I'm not so sure of having access to the logic that generates the cookie.

Comment: Now that I think on it, it is unlikely you can write a cookie for a different domain in a client page. Your best bet is to make the cookie apply to all subdomains when initially issued.